# Select more checkbox by value on different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I asked how to select more checkbox by value, and it works well. 
See here the question: [Select more checkbox by value or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654698/select-more-checkbox-by-value-or-id)
But now I would like to know if you can select these checkboxes if I have 2 divverenti div, here is an example:

```
<div class="checkbox_option1">
  <div class="icheckbox" style="position: relative;">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQHb" value="Italy">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQrt" value="Germany">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQzx" value="France">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox_option2">
  <div class="icheckbox" style="position: relative;">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQHb" value="Italy">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQrt" value="Germany">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQzx" value="France">
    <input class="checkbox_filter" type="checkbox" id="ffQzx" value="France">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like that the toggle select only those of the `<div class="checkbox_option2">` it's possible? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery child selectors, I think it will be of use:  https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Building off the solution to your prior question, you would use something along these lines:

```
var check_germany = $(".checkbox_option2 > input:checkbox[value=Germany]");
```

Comment: This will not work, though. As they're not direct children of the `.checkbox_option2` div! Just a space will do!

Comment: it's possible make this:
var check_germany = $(".checkbox_option2 > .icheckbox > input:checkbox[value=Germany]");
?

Answer (score 0):

Yes use parent-child selectors (using `>`) if they're direct children like:

```
$("div.checkbox_option2 > input:checkbox[value=Germany]")...
```

Or just a space () if they're children or children of children ...etc like:

```
$("div.checkbox_option2 input:checkbox[value=Germany]")...
```

In your case the second one will work.

More about CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).